# Blade: anonymous component doesn't show when passing data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Blade and tried to use anonymous components for sections that I will use frequently.
The problem is that when I'm trying to pass down data to the component, it won't show anything.

Here is my Code:

Controller:

```
public function edit(Workingtime $workingtime)
    {
      $user = User::find(Auth::id());
      $workingtime_array = $user->getWorkingtimesOfThisDay($workingtime->id);
            
      return view('workingtime-edit', compact('workingtime_array', 'workingtime'));     
    }
```

workingtime-edit.blade.php:

```
<p>Overview of Workingtimes</p>

@if(count($workingtime_array) > 0)
    <x-workingtime-timeline :workingtimeArray = "$workingtime_array"/>
@endif
```

workingtime-timeline.blade.php (component):

```
@props(['workingtimeArray']) 

@php

    if(isset($workingtimeArray) AND count ($workingtimeArray) > 0){
        $start = strtotime($workingtimeArray[0]->time_begin);
        $end = strtotime($workingtimeArray[count($workingtimeArray)-1]->time_end);
    } 

@endphp

@foreach ($workingtimeArray as $worktime)

    <p>Start: {{ $worktime->time_begin }} </p>
    <p>End: {{ $worktime->time_end }} </p>

@endforeach;
```

When I don't use variables and @props, it shows me the content of the component.

I tried to change the `<x-workingtime-timeline :workingtimeArray = "$workingtime_array"/>` line but nothing worked.

Things I tried:

`<x-workingtime-timeline :workingtimeArray = "$workingtime_array"> </x-workingtime-timeline>`

`<x-workingtime-timeline workingtimeArray = "$workingtime_array"/>`

Comment: Verify that the workingtime-timeline.blade.php component file is located in the appropriate directory, which is typically resources/views/components by default. Ensure that the file name and case sensitivity match.
Check if the component is registered in the AppServiceProvider or any other service provider in your application. Look for the boot method and ensure that it includes the following line:

Blade::component('workingtime-timeline', 'x-workingtime-timeline');

Comment: @henrik the component is correctly located and the names match,
I didn't do anything in AppServiceProvider.php or any other provider in app/Providers. They are all default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `workingtime-edit.blade.php` you need to remove the spaces around the `=` for the attribute you are setting:

```
<x-workingtime-timeline :workingtimeArray="$workingtime_array"/>
```

I think this is a limitation of Laravel's parsing of component attributes, since this is not a general requirement of HTML attributes.